# click button, show only one animation if not visible

Tags: jquery, hidden, visible

I've tried to get this working with various methods - all without joy - i have a couple of  animations and two buttons. I would appreciate any help

The animations are initially hidden - i need an 'if' statement which allows only one animation to show at any one point - here's my hash of code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
//hide bubble facts
$('#bubble02,#bubble03').css("display", "none");
$('#fact02,#fact03').css("display", "none");        

//btn02
$('#btn02').click(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
$('#bubble02').fadeIn();
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
$('#bubble02').fadeOut();
$('#fact02').fadeIn();
}, 6000);
setTimeout(function() {
$('#fact02').hide();
}, 12000);
});


//btn03
$('#btn03').click(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
$('#bubble03').fadeIn();
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
$('#bubble03').fadeOut();
$('#fact03').fadeIn();
}, 6000);
setTimeout(function() {
$('#fact03').hide();
}, 12000);
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit more.? I could not get you.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://tinyurl.com/onanufn - if you click on the buttons on the top the bubbles fade in and the animation begins - i only want one bubble visible at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using fadeIn(); fadeOut(); with a delay(); and then using finish(); to cancel the animation!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "chained animation" you have to use the callbacks, something like this:

```
$('#btn02').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#bubble02').fadeIn(100, function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#bubble02').fadeOut();
                $('#fact02').fadeIn(100, function(){
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#fact02').hide();
                    }, 12000);
                });
            }, 6000);
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: ok thanks - but i only need one "chained animation" to show at one time. i.e. if you click btn02 the bubble02 animation plays, if you click btn03 the bubble02 animation disappears and the bubble03 animation plays

Comment: That was an example for using the callbacks, from that you have to think the order of the animation. i.e. bbl3 appear, bbl2 blink, bbl2 fadeout.. etc

Comment: Thanks but that's not really what im after mate - the whole reason im using setTimeout is because there is information in the bubble that needs reading, the bubble needs to fade out and the fact bubble needs to fade up - im happy with that code - what i need is for one animation to show at a time

Comment: ok great - looks better now - now i just need one animation to play at a time